# How to get RoleProvider from web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, membership-provider, roleprovider

I want to write a custom role provider which has two other role provider. I have written a custom membership provider like this:

```
public class CustomMemberProvider : MembershipProvider
{
    MembershipProvider _sqlProvider = null;
    MembershipProvider sqlProvider
    {
        get
        {
            if (_sqlProvider == null)
                _sqlProvider = System.Web.Security.Membership.Providers["SqlProvider"] as SqlMembershipProvider;
            return _sqlProvider;
        }

    }
    MembershipProvider _adProvider = null;
    MembershipProvider adProvider
    {
        get
        {
            if (_adProvider == null)
                _adProvider = System.Web.Security.Membership.Providers["AdProvider"] as MembershipProvider;
            return _adProvider;
        }

    }
    ....
```

now , i want to get those two role provider from the web.config too, something like this:

```
public class CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
    private static readonly string m_RoleProviderNamePrefix = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RoleProviderName"] + ":";

    RoleProvider _sqlProvider = null;
    RoleProvider sqlProvider
    {
        get
        {
            if (_sqlProvider == null)
                _sqlProvider = ??????
            return _sqlProvider;
        }

    }
    RoleProvider _adProvider = null;
    RoleProvider adProvider
    {
        get
        {
            if (_adProvider == null)
                _adProvider = ??????
            return _adProvider;
        }

    }
```

i can not find any method to get that, please help me, thank you.

Comment: Did you try System.Web.Security.Roles.Providers property? It returns  RoleProviderCollection, a collection of the role providers for the ASP.NET application.

Answer (score 0):

You plug in your providers via the web.config's built-in sections.  They don't need to reference each other, they just need to implement the proper functionality that the providers expect.

Membership provider example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e9y4s5t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Role provider ( tag) example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tksy7hd7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx